# Как пройти верификацию пакетов приложения для Windows 10 mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-10-mobile

Не удается пройти Validation(верификацию) пакетов приложения(app packages) для ARM девайсов, т.е для Windows 10 mobile. Создаются пакеты, потом выйдет окно Validation. Я подключил смартфон через USB и активировал режим разработчика. Но там стоит Local machine и Remote machine. Выбирал Local machine, но кнопка Launch Windows App Certification Kit не активна. Мое приложение только для мобильных устройств. Как можно пройти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте запустить вручную из Пуск - Windows Kits - Windows App Cert Kit